# Using Spring mongoTemplate to construct a query to find an element of an array or update the element of an array

Tags: spring, criteria, mongotemplate

Can anyone convert this to mongo query.  The queries I've tried always produce something slightly different and fails.

Correct Result:

```
db.mailbox.find
( { "user_id" : "2"}, 
  {_id: 0, mails: 
  {$elemMatch:   {conversation_id: "3"}}}
);
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
Query find = new Query(
Criteria.where("user_id").is("2"))
.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(0))
.addCriteria(Criteria.where("mails")
.elemMatch(Criteria.where("conversation_id").is("3") ));
```

Result:

```
db.mailbox.find({ "user_id" : "2" , "_id" : 0 , "mails" : 
{ "$elemMatch" : { "conversation_id" : "3"}}});
```

I've also tried this to increment the unread field:

```
db.mailbox.update({"user_id": "2", mails: 
{$elemMatch: {conversation_id: "3"}} , 
{$inc:{"mails.$.unread":1}})

mongoTemplate.findAndModify(
Query.query(Criteria.where("user_id").is("2").and("mails")
.elemMatch(Criteria.where("conversation_id").is("3"))),  new Update()
.inc("mails.$.unread", 1), MailBox.class);
```

And I end up with this error:

```
{ "user_id" : "2" , "mails" : { "$elemMatch" : 
{ "conversation_id" : "3"}}} 

fields: null sort: null for class: class MailBox and update: 
{ "$inc" : { "mails.$.unread" : 1}} in collection: mailbox
```

Comment: could you beautify the code, please? horizontal scrolling is a pain in the .... :)